# ZF2. Alternative to having the AbstractController (or another classes) implementing the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface?

Tags: testing, dependency-injection, zend-framework2, inversion-of-control, service-locator

At this [blog post](http://macnibblet.blogspot.se/2013/10/why-i-wish-to-remove-getservicelocator.html) one can read three reasons to avoid `$this->getServiceLocator()` inside controllers. I think that those reasons are valid not just into a controller class but in whatever class that implement the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` interface.

Most times is considered an anti pattern get the dependencies injected using the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`? In what cases this pattern could not be considered an anti pattern and why?

Can anybody elaborate on how an alternative solution (presumably using *Zend\DI* I think) could be? More specifically, how to avoid the use of `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` *Modules*, *Controllers* and *Bussiness/Domain* classes. I'm interesting in know about performance issues around Zend\DI and its solutions.

**EDIT**

Worth define factories for classes with two or three dependencies when the only thing I will get at the end is move the "injector code" (former `$this->getServiceLocator()->get($serviceName)`) to factories without solving the testing problem at all? Of course that  I will want test my factories too? or no?

I think that factories must be reserved to situations where objects build involve complex tasks. Seem to me that when classes have few dependencies and zero logic (beside the dependency resolving) factories solutions is an overkill of this problem. Beside, with this solution I will end with more code to tests (factories) and with more tests (to test factories) while trying avoid less code in tests implementation. Mocking service locator is an easy thing, cos the interface just have two method and the mocking code could be shared between all tests cases.

Pls, rectify me if I'm wrong ;)

*Zend\DI* could help, but I will be graceful if someone elaborate about the specifics of this kind of solution.

**EDIT 2**

Few weeks ago [this](http://www.zend.com/en/webinar/Framework/70170000000cBiR-DDD-ZF2-20130925.flv) Zend webinar ("An introduction to Domain Driven Design with ZF2") used this anti-pattern (39:05). I'm right now wandering until what point this's really an anti-pattern ;)

And [here](http://macnibblet.blogspot.se/2013/10/why-i-wish-to-remove-getservicelocator.html) more info about this issue.

What Fowler have to said about is [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ServiceLocatorVsDependencyInjection)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually really easy to solve this problem, inject your dependencies via the constructor. This removes a lot of the magic that will cause problems in larger applications.

So this means you need to create factories instead of using invokable classes.
As seen in the documentation here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Antoine. I agreed with you that constructor injection is one solution, but my question is about how specifically implement that solution (or another one) in the ZF2 context. E.g. where I could define *Module* classes's factories?(if is that I can do such thing without change the ModuleManager implementation) I will edit my question right now to add some others concerns about this issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Thats a question of personal taste... i usually place my factories outside of the context folder.

So if have a Controller "Foo\Controller\IndexController"
I would place the factory in "Foo\ControllerFactory\IndexControllerFactory"

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but if you said that this is antipatern injecting ServiceLocator via interface, how about zend initializers for me its almost the same thing. When you make instance of your class by ServiceManager initializer checks if your class implements particular interface after that you inject dependency using setter.

Comment: They are also considered bad practise by many people due to the issues they cause and the poor implementation. But you should try and speak to ocramius about that....

http://www.twitter.com/ocramius

Answer (score 0):

Last ZF2 version (zendframework/zend-mvc 2.7.0 and +) throws `Depracated` warnings if you use the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface, and ZF docs (*at the time writing this answer*) is not clear and still use this interface. ZF 'gurus' don't talk about updating the docs. It's hard to find a concrete exemple if you are not a ZF2 expert (*at the time writing this answer*).

But fortunately, Rob Allen wrote a post some years ago to explain how to remove the SL dependency and inject it in your controller : https://akrabat.com/injecting-dependencies-into-your-zf2-controllers/ This solve the problem. Hope this will help !